# ASP .NET + IIS + Crystal Reports + Load report failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, crystal-reports

I am developping a web application by using the ASP .NET MVC 3 framework.
I have implemented an ASPX page containing a CrystalReportViewer control.

I instantiate a ReportDocument object in my Page_Load event method of my ASPX page.
Then I load a RPT file by using the Load method of my ReportDocument.

My RPT is correctly loaded when I use the VS2010 development web server and I can view it through my viewer.
But the call to the Load method of my ReportDocument raises an exception when I use my IIS 5.1 local web server.

Here are some information about the exception :

- Exception Type : CrystalReportsException
- Message : Load report failed
- StackTrace :

  à CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
  à CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
  à CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
  à ASP.aspnetforms_editionresultats_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) dans .aspx:ligne 43
  à System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
  à System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  à System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  à System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
  à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Does someone know why the exception is raised when I use IIS ?

Comment: First suggestion: try moving your code to Page_Init

Comment: Do you have the correct Crystal runtimes installed on the server? (version and architecture)

Comment: @EmanueleGreco : I have tried to move my code into the Page_Init event method but I am still facing the exception.

Comment: @LeeTickett : Crystal runtimes are correctly installed on my IIS 5.1 local server. I have got a virtual directory named aspnet_client with correct content under my default web site.

Comment: what credentials (permissions) are IIS and AppPool running under? Where is the .rpt file?

Comment: @LeeTickett : I am beginner with IIS. Please tell me how I can view the IIS and AppPool permissions from the WinXP IIS Administrative Tools. My .rpt file is under a folder named reports. The reports folder is under the Content directory. And the Content directory is under my application root folder.

Comment: @user1139666: put your code here. you need to dispose the report object every time because crystal report create the temp.crt file into temp location. there is limit of creating this temp file. when temp full then it's throw this error.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        this.CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
        this.CrystalReportViewer1 = null;
        // CrystalReportViewer1.Close();
        // CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
        GC.Collect();

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    cryRpt.Load("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\CrystalReportDemo\\CrystalReport.rpt");
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and what I did to solve the 'Load Report Failed' problem.

1. First check whether your report folder exists or `.rpt` files in your project folder after you publish the asp.net project. I simply placed my whole project folder in the IIS root directory. I am using the my reports in 'Reports' folder that doesn't cause any error.
2. Then copy `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13” into your project main folder like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\YourProjectFolder\`.

Please, comment when this doesn't work.